# MySQL: Update two tables (if email is in both)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table 'userdata' with a lot of rows containing the fields *id, name, email, etc., IsBL* and another table 'blacklist' with the fields *id, group, email, xcount*

I do an update with the following code:

```
UPDATE `userdata` AS `dest`,
         (SELECT * FROM `blacklist` WHERE `group` = "3") AS `src`
SET `dest`.`IsBL` = '1' 
WHERE `dest`.`email` = `src`.`email`
```

This works as expected. Furthermore I want to increase the 'xcount' field all the time a mail address is equal on both tables. Is there a way to do it?

I tried

```
SET `dest`.`IsBL` = '1', `src`.`xcount` = `src`.`xcount` + 1
WHERE `dest`.`email` = `src`.`email`
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: Two updated statements - Update src , then update target.

Comment: Have a look at [mysql IF statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html)

Comment: How does it not work, it throws an error, updates only one column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't update `src` because it isn't actually a table. You need to `JOIN` the `blacklist` table instead and include the `WHERE group = 3` condition with the condition on `email`:

```
UPDATE `userdata` AS `dest`, `blacklist` AS `src`
SET `dest`.`IsBL` = '1', `src`.`xcount` = `src`.`xcount` + 1
WHERE `dest`.`email` = `src`.`email` AND
      `src`.`group` = 3
```

Comment: This is almost perfect! Thanks :) Is there a way to only update xcount, if the IsBL is changed?

Comment: You could add ``dest`.`IsBL` !=1` to the `WHERE` clause

Comment: Thanks!  This helped me a lot!